# Console App into windows service using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, .net-4.8, topshelf

I am trying to convert my console application into windows service using .net4.8. I used the topshelf to create a service. The frequency of my service will be every minute. I don't know if I am doing it correctly to call the method within the constructor APIService. Here's my code:

**APIService.cs**

```
    public APIService()
{
    // code here for login in the application
     
    // calling the method class
    SAPAPI.PostRequest(uri);
    SLMAPI.PostRequest(uri);

    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60) { AutoReset = true };
    _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
}

private void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = new string[] { DateTime.Now.ToString() };
    File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\ProgramData\temp\Timer.txt", lines);
}

public void Start()
{
    _timer.Start();
}

public void Stop()
{
    _timer.Stop();
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x => 
    {
        x.Service<APIService>(a => 
        {
            a.ConstructUsing(apiservice => new APIService());
            a.WhenStarted(apiservice => apiservice .Start());
            a.WhenStopped(apiservice => apiservice .Stop());
        });

        x.RunAsLocalSystem();

        x.SetServiceName("ClientWindowService");
        x.SetDisplayName("Client Window Service");
    });

    int exitCodeValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
    Environment.ExitCode = exitCodeValue;
}
```

Have I done it correctly? Does it automatically trigger the service every minute based on my code?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: why not just try it out and see what happens?

Comment: Look at your Timer.txt file and you will know.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) and [Tutorial: Create a Windows service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#set-up-the-polling-mechanism)

Comment: The interval is in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: It is not calling my method automatically . Whats wrong with my code?